# How can i open PDF file using UIView in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, pdf

How can I open or display PDF file without using `UIWebView`. I need to use `UIView` for horizontal `scroll` for PDF View.

Comment: Google it. http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `UIWebView`?  You can access the underlying scroll view (`scrollView` property in iOS 5+, and even before iOS 5, you can still find it among the UIWebView's `subviews`).  That would allow you to change the default scrolling behaviour of a `UIWebView`.

Comment: I made a gist a while ago https://gist.github.com/1905400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If don't want to use UIWebView then your alternative is to use [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for showing PDF file.

Can also use [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/)

Check [sample from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052) ie docInteraction  for more reference.

Comment: hi, can QLPreviewController make a horizontal scroll of pdf? the given sample has only vertical scroll to pdf... any pointer to creating a horizontal scroll for pdf is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Check out the OpenSource [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) project on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Look up `CGPDFDocument` and the related APIs.  That should get you going.